# Ant Design Browser support

Tags: cross-browser, antd, backwards-compatibility

I went through an use case where my team has to choose a React component library. One of the evaluation criteria is the browser support, but the AntDesign docs says that it support the last two versions of the popular browsers: https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Environment-Support

Is it limited to the last two versions or are those only recomendations?

Other libraries like MaterialUI states very well which versions it supports: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/